# unable to change the status of check box in the react virtual dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello i am looping multiple check boxes on left side , based on checked check boxes , pushing the checked status and value of that check box in right side and showing as a check box , if i unchecked the right side check box it disappear applied by me but after disappearing the right side check boxes then on the left side check box should be update as uncheck... but dom is not updating as unchecked ....can any one help on these
this is the link of code sand box  : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-eoiiv?file=/demo.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "react-grid-system";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const courses = [
  { id: 1, value: "MPC", isChecked: false },
  { id: 2, value: "CEC", isChecked: false },
  { id: 3, value: "HEC", isChecked: false },
  { id: 4, value: "BIPC", isChecked: false }
];

export default class Abc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      CheckedCourses: [],
      courses: []
    };
  }
  handleCheckChieldElement = event => {
    courses.forEach(course => {
      if (course.value === event.target.value)
        course.isChecked = event.target.checked;
    });
    this.setState({ courses: courses });
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.state.CheckedCourses.push({
        checked: event.target.checked,
        value: event.target.value
      });
    } else {
      this.state.CheckedCourses.splice(
        this.state.CheckedCourses.indexOf({
          checked: event.target.checked,
          value: event.target.value
        }),
        1
      );
    }
    console.log(this.state.CheckedCourses);
    this.setState({
      CheckedCourses: this.state.CheckedCourses
    });
  };
  removeCourse = event => {
    this.state.CheckedCourses.splice(
      this.state.CheckedCourses.indexOf({
        checked: event.target.checked,
        value: event.target.value
      }),
      1
    );
    this.setState({
      CheckedCourses: this.state.CheckedCourses
    });
    console.log(this.state.CheckedCourses);
    courses.forEach(course => {
      if (course.value === event.target.value)
        course.isChecked = event.target.checked;
    });
    this.setState({
      courses: this.state.courses
    });
    console.log(this.state.courses);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Row>
          <Col sm={6}>
            {courses.map((course, key) => (
              <div key={key}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={this.state.isChecked}
                      onClick={this.handleCheckChieldElement}
                      value={course.value}
                    />
                  }
                  label={course.value}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Col>
          <Col sm={6}>
            {this.state.CheckedCourses.map((CheckedCourse, key) => (
              <div key={key}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={CheckedCourse.checked}
                      onClick={this.removeCourse}
                      value={CheckedCourse.value}
                    />
                  }
                  label={CheckedCourse.value}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not manipulate `checked` status of DOM element directly, instead you should bind that to state, thus when unchecked it will update respective state value and consequently re-draw bound element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide whether you want to render your `const courses` or `courses` in your state. There is a conflict between them in your code. Here is a working version, if i understand correctly. The problem was here `checked={this.state.isChecked}`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3y0jk) is your final codebox

Comment: thanks for your answer acbay....its working very much fine....i think some thing wrong with my code....can you help on the slicing  the same check box when unchecked check box.....

Comment: I would like to help you but I don't understand what you exactly want

Comment: you can check in the code sand box.....if i checked the left side all check boxes, it will appear right all check boxes...if tried to un-check of mpc on left side...on the right side bipc check box is disappearing....its slicing based on index...i do not want to do like that....

Comment: By the way there is nothing wrong with using slice while you are not manipulating the state directly. But i did not use it, cause you dont want it